# Where did the extra crew come from in Andromeda S03E12-The Dark Backward?

Tags: andromeda

First question here, pretty long time lurker.

Not sure how much of a spoiler this is, but just in case:

In S03E12 *The Dark Backward*, where:

> Trance is going through all the possible variations of the scenario to find the perfect possible future in which the crew of the Andromeda make it through the crisis with no one dying, suddenly there are other crew-members aside from the main 5? For example, there's a security force and crew working in the slip stream core. As far as I know previously there have never been mentions of the addition of crew members, and I'm a couple episodes past this and no mention has been made again of additional crew.

Where did these people come from? Where did they go? Am I thinking too hard about this? (Probably yes to the third, I know.) If there's an explanation further on (though I doubt it) please just let me know without any spoilers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Season three was confusing because it had the full High guard crew appear and disappear several times. Season three also had many plot holes and inconsistencies.
You can read about it here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Andromeda_episodes)
The reason why S3 was so inconsistent is because the show's original developer and main writer (Robert Hewitt Wolfe) left after season 2 because he refused to make the show less intellectual and complex.

Comment: Couldn't upvote, not enough rep. :( But thank you! Will chug through, hope it gets less loopy!

Comment: Ahh, that explains everything. That's why I couldn't finish watching S3

Comment: For interest - this is how it should have ended... http://www.cyberspace5.net/agentrichard07/coda.htm

Comment: @Liath: Wow, thanks! That was outstanding!

Comment: @djm Keep it in mind if you go back and watch Season 1 again.  It's amazing how many things he set up that slipped through the cracks because their significance wasn't known at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the crew consists of members from restored commonwealth as well as half the crew from the bellaprahn when the crew commits mutiny against its Captain.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: Hunt grants them a way out then being left on the planet that their captain offered.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a for sure thing but I recognize the first officer Nadia also standing of the bellaphran standing on Andromeda's bridge one to two episodes after leaving bellaphran and yes for sure to some of them come from restored common wealth as well as that is obvious that no one else survived from the past so obviously they had to come from there.